# PowerPivot: Column - Min(Column)

Tags: excel, powerpivot

new to powerpivot here. I have a power pivot table imported from power query as shown below

```
      Value    Name
      (blank)  301 -  PPFV Parametrics Rl
      100      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      100.5    301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      101      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      101.5    301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      102      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      102.5    301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      103      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      103.5    301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      104      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      104.5    301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      105      301 -  ZLIMrl3Q
      42       301 -  ZLIMCVmQ
      42.5     301 -  ZLIMCVmQ
      43       301 -  ZLIMCVmQ
      43.5     301 -  ZLIMCVmQ
      44       301 -  ZLIMCVmQ
```

I would like to calculate the spread. meaning the column - min(column). I need  to be only for the rows with the same name. e.g column - min(ZLIMCVmQ).

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPivot is quite different from Excel. The calculations are done with row context.

To get MIN for values matching the one in the row, you would use the powerful CALCULATE function with EARLIER function. You need to look up these functions to understand how they work.

```
Min = [Value]-CALCULATE(Min([Value]),FILTER('Table1',[Name]=EARLIER([Name])))
```

[image]

You can find the difference from current row value with this:

```
Diff = [Value]-CALCULATE(Min([Value]),FILTER('Table1',[Name]=EARLIER([Name]))
```

Comment: it works perfectly. However, when i try to reload another mdb file from power query to excel table, this error message appears. "There were errors trying to update one or more linked tables....". When i remove the calculated columns the table loads without any problems. Why is that?

Comment: Thats strange. I guess you are updating Table1 with a PowerQuery. Are you linking Table1 to any other table?

Comment: Hi eshwar, it is linked to another excel table called "Path". It is a defined range where i choose the mdb file path. It is present in the rest of my tables as well.